# Display a DynamoDB tabel on a S3 Static website

Tags: html, amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb

Hi I want to display a complete DynamoDB tabel on a static website hostet on a S3 bucket.

The tabel looks like:

Id---Name---Surname---Date of Birth

Is there an html statement that reads form the dynamo db and displays its content on the site?
Later i would like to search or only display some entries but right now i need them all.

I heard it would work with html but Im a novice in terms of it.